# Use domain as "prefix" on CakePHP

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting, prefix

Let's say that I have a site running CakePHP and I have the prefix "product".

I have lots of pages with URL like:

```
http://mysite.com/produt/blue-shirt/details
http://mysite.com/produt/blue-shirt/order
http://mysite.com/produt/skate/details
http://mysite.com/produt/sun-glasses/vendors
```

Now I need to use a domain like `http://mysite-blue-shirt.com/` as "shortcut" to the blue-shirt product, and my URLs will become:

```
http://mysite-blue-shirt.com/details
http://mysite-blue-shirt.com/order
```

What I need to do?

I think that's something with the `.htaccess` on the root of the website, outside the `app` directory.

Here's the current syntax:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond    %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite-blue-shirt\.com
   RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product/blue-shirt
   RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ app/webroot/product/blue-shirt/$1 [L]

   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The first line checks the site's name. The second one checks if it has already not been re-written to blue-shirt. The final line carries out the rewrite.

Comment: Shouldn't be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/index.php?url=product/blue-shirt/$1 [L]`?

Comment: That works too. Take a look at the .htaccess file in app/webroot. It would be better to rewrite things the way my edited answer shows. Or, you could possibly add the QSA flag to your rule to attach any query strings. Remember to test this thoroughly, as corner cases can easily develop (such as redirection from within Cake).

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to create your own custom Routing class. Check this: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp

Answer (score 0):

For the outside world to see this you would need to register mysite-blue-shirt and all the other variants.

Comment: I'm not talkin about domains... I'm askin about **how I do it**, using htaccess or hackin into CakePHP :)